# kafka consumer threads are in waiting state and lag is getting increased

Tags: performance, apache-kafka

currently i am using kafka 0.8.0 and high level consumer group to consume messages. topic has been created with 3 replica and 100 partition so that max 100 threads can consume messages simultaneously, but i am seeing that mostly threads are in waiting state and lag is getting increased.

Below is output of **kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker**

```
kafka.coms.consumer.kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms.coms-timemachine.coms.coms04.snapdeal.com kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms 91  119585          142834          23249           kafka.coms.consumer.kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms.coms-timemachine.coms.coms04.snapdeal.com_coms04.snapdeal.com-1396988657075-27d01963-64
        kafka.coms.consumer.kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms.coms-timemachine.coms.coms04.snapdeal.com kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms 92  84963           144019          59056           kafka.coms.consumer.kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms.coms-timemachine.coms.coms04.snapdeal.com_coms04.snapdeal.com-1396988657075-27d01963-65
        kafka.coms.consumer.kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms.coms-timemachine.coms.coms04.snapdeal.com kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms 93  723228          776541          53313           kafka.coms.consumer.kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms.coms-timemachine.coms.coms04.snapdeal.com_coms04.snapdeal.com-1396988657075-27d01963-66
        kafka.coms.consumer.kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms.coms-timemachine.coms.coms04.snapdeal.com kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms 94  93068           143567          50499           kafka.coms.consumer.kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms.coms-timemachine.coms.coms04.snapdeal.com_coms04.snapdeal.com-1396988657075-27d01963-67
        kafka.coms.consumer.kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms.coms-timemachine.coms.coms04.snapdeal.com kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms 95  84419           143149          58730           kafka.coms.consumer.kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms.coms-timemachine.coms.coms04.snapdeal.com_coms04.snapdeal.com-1396988657075-27d01963-68
        kafka.coms.consumer.kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms.coms-timemachine.coms.coms04.snapdeal.com kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms 96  727430          777824          50394           kafka.coms.consumer.kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms.coms-timemachine.coms.coms04.snapdeal.com_coms04.snapdeal.com-1396988657075-27d01963-69
        kafka.coms.consumer.kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms.coms-timemachine.coms.coms04.snapdeal.com kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms 97  104414          143725          39311           kafka.coms.consumer.kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms.coms-timemachine.coms.coms04.snapdeal.com_coms04.snapdeal.com-1396988657075-27d01963-7
        kafka.coms.consumer.kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms.coms-timemachine.coms.coms04.snapdeal.com kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms 98  84337           143264          58927           kafka.coms.consumer.kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms.coms-timemachine.coms.coms04.snapdeal.com_coms04.snapdeal.com-1396988657075-27d01963-8
        kafka.coms.consumer.kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms.coms-timemachine.coms.coms04.snapdeal.com kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms 99  721316          777124          55808           kafka.coms.consumer.kafka_topic_coms_esb_prod_coms.coms-timemachine.coms.coms04.snapdeal.com_coms04.snapdeal.com-1396988657075-27d01963-9
```

Below is out put of **consumer thread group's thread_dump**

```
 KafkaConsumer-24" prio=10 tid=0x00007f6da5726800 nid=0x3c8a waiting on condition [0x00007f6d4f8f7000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c11ce780> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
            at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
            at kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator.makeNext(ConsumerIterator.scala:63)
            at kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator.makeNext(ConsumerIterator.scala:33)
            at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.maybeComputeNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:61)
            at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.hasNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:53)
            at com.snapdeal.coms.kafka.KafkaEventListenerContainer$KafkaConsumer.safeRun(KafkaEventListenerContainer.java:141)
            at com.snapdeal.coms.kafka.KafkaEventListenerContainer$KafkaConsumer.run(KafkaEventListenerContainer.java:175)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

    "KafkaConsumer-23" prio=10 tid=0x00007f6da5724000 nid=0x3c89 waiting on condition [0x00007f6d4f9f8000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c11cde90> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
            at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
            at kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator.makeNext(ConsumerIterator.scala:63)
            at kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator.makeNext(ConsumerIterator.scala:33)
            at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.maybeComputeNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:61)
            at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.hasNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:53)
            at com.snapdeal.coms.kafka.KafkaEventListenerContainer$KafkaConsumer.safeRun(KafkaEventListenerContainer.java:141)
            at com.snapdeal.coms.kafka.KafkaEventListenerContainer$KafkaConsumer.run(KafkaEventListenerContainer.java:175)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
```

I am not sure why my consumer thread's are waiting on this condition if messages are available in kafka partition.